# How to use react-toastify outside component and use react component as body of it

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-toastify

I have a file called agent.ts that contains axios interceptors.
In those interceptors I watch for any status code that is >= 400 and <= 500.
When such error occurs, I am invoking react-toastify toast.

Everything works perfect so far.
What I want to be able to do though, is to use html as body of the message.
Usually I would do that by creating a custom component and then using the component as body of the toast message. But because I am using react-toastify outsode of component in a regular typescript file, I am getting an compilation error.

Here is part of my code:

```js
axios.interceptors.response.use(undefined, async (error) => {
  if (error.message === 'Network Error' && !error.response) {
    toast.error('Network error - make sure API is running!');
  }

  const { status, data } = error.response;

  if (status >= 400 && status < 500) {
    if (!data || !data.errors) {
      toast.error(`${status} API error. Please check the terminal!`);
      return;
    }

    console.warn('API Errors:', data.errors);
    Object.keys(data.errors).forEach(function (key) {
      toast.warn(data.errors[key].toString());
    });
  }

  if (status === 500) {
    toast.error('Server error - check the terminal for more info!');
  }

  throw error.response;
});
```

I am attaching a screenshot of the compile error that I see:
[image]

Can you please advice me what is the best approach here ?

Answer (score 0):

If you read the [API docs](https://react-hot-toast.com/docs/toast), there's a section that allows custom styling under `options.style`, as well as adding custom class names. To do what you tried though, you can also use `toast.custom`:

```
toast.custom(<div>...</div>);
```

Comment: Hey mate,
I think you are talking about different library. react-hot-toast, while I was refering to react-toastify (https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-toastify).

Anyway, your comment is still usefull, because I can use this as an alternative and completely change the library that I am using in case I cannot manage to fix the issue mentioned in the post.

Comment: @DobromirIvanov oh, I'm sorry. I didn't see that you specified in your question and assumed it was React Hot Toast.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find solution.
Basically I was able to use react components by changing the file type of the agent.ts from .ts to .tsx. Thats it, you I don't need anything else.

As an alternative if this approach is not working for some reason, I can also use React.createElement() directly:

```
let node = React.createElement('div', null, `Hello`, React.createElement('br', null),React.createElement('br', null), "world!");
```